# How to configure mysql group replication with different ports?

Tags: mysql, group-replication, kubernetes

I have a k8s cluster and each `mysql` instance is well connected together! But I have another `mysql` server outside the cluster! Each `mysql` inside the cluster has a default `mysql` port, which is `3306` and an external port; which is something random! So when I start `mysql` group replication with the instances that are inside the cluster everything works fine!

the thing is the `mysql` instance that is outside of the cluster is trying to connect to the `3306` default port with `repl` user but it should be connecting to the random port generated! and I don't know how to specify it to connect to the port I want to connect...

**how can i specify the outsider instance to use that random generated port to connect to other instances inside the cluster to use mysql group replication?**

here is my error log:

```
error connecting to master 'repl@db1-headless:3306'
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a pretty neat utility called `redir` that accept connections on the configured port and then redirect it to the another port inside the infrastructure.

You have to run a script that should:

- query some cluster member for its external port number $RANDOM
- start `redir --laddr=a.b.c.d --lport=33036 --cport=$RANDOM`
- be configured as service with autorestart and proper precedence (after mysql)

Here `redir` will redirect all incoming connections to the localhost, but `--caddr=z.y.x.w` can be specified. Refer to `redir(1)` manpage for further reading.